# Невозможно скомпилировать android проект в студии

Tags: java, android, netty

Пишу свое приложение, в котором необходимо будет использовать сервер. Сегодня наткнулся на замечательную библиотеку [Netty](http://netty.io/). Взял вот [этот](https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/securechat) пример и запустил. Десктопная версия работает на ура. Решил модернизировать код под свои нужды, добавил все исходные классы примера в свой андроид проект и повесил на кнопку исполнение данного метода:

```
public static void startAndroidSecureChatClient() throws Exception{
    // Configure SSL.
    final SslContext sslCtx = SslContextBuilder.forClient()
            .trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE).build();

    EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    try {
        Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
        b.group(group)
                .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                .handler(new SecureChatClientInitializer(sslCtx));

        // Start the connection attempt.
        Channel ch = b.connect(HOST2, PORT).sync().channel();

        // Read commands from the stdin.
        ChannelFuture lastWriteFuture = null;
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        for (;;) {
            String line = in.readLine();
            if (line == null) {
                break;
            }

            // Sends the received line to the server.
            lastWriteFuture = ch.writeAndFlush(line + "\r\n");

            // If user typed the 'bye' command, wait until the server closes
            // the connection.
            if ("bye".equals(line.toLowerCase())) {
                ch.closeFuture().sync();
                break;
            }
        }

        // Wait until all messages are flushed before closing the channel.
        if (lastWriteFuture != null) {
            lastWriteFuture.sync();
        }
    } finally {
        // The connection is closed automatically on shutdown.
        group.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

После попытки компиляции выдает ошибку:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':android:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
> org/jboss/marshalling/ByteInput
```

Библиотеку вставлял, переустанавливал, Clean, Rebuild делал. В чем может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте отключить Instant Run в настройках Android Studio
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]